# Oracle 11g R2 Excel Import Issue

Tags: java, sql, excel, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a database and import some data I have in an Excel spreadsheet straight into it.
The spreadsheet has around 65,500 rows and 14 columns so it is a fair amount of data.

So far I have

- Installed and setup Oracle 11g R2
- Created a database which is currently empty
- Used Enterprise Manager to create a new tablespace with 5 GB space and privileges
- Installed SQL Developer and connected to the database with two connections (one user and one admin (system account))
- I have also increased the VM in both sqldeveloper.conf and the ide.conf

The problem I am having is that once I right click ‘Tables (Filtered)’ and try to import data, once I go through the dialog box and define all the column types and space for them, the process fails and I get an error saying, ‘Import Data into table SuppPerf from file supplier performance data.xls . Task failed and import rolled back.’
I also get ‘Java heap space’ and ‘GC overhead limit exceeded’.

Any ideas on what is happening and how I can retify this?

Comment: How big is the excel file?  65,500 rows with 14 columns really isn't that much, unless each column is free form text.  Did you try converting the excel to CSV and import?  does it work for Just 1-2 rows?

Comment: 65,500 is awfully close to the old Excel limit of 65,536.  I wonder if that's related somehow.  Can you remove some rows and try again?

Comment: @xQbert the Excel is 27.5mb and no unfortunately it still doesnt work with a few rows. It also doesn't work when I save it as a CSV. Which leads me to believe it may be something wrong on the sql side (I just have no idea what).

Comment: @JonHeller It does go all the way to 65,536 rows. So I made a second excel file where I only copied the first 33 (just the top few) entries so that one is 33 rows and 14 columns, still with the same error unfortunately

Comment: All I can think of is that one of the column labels, data types or data contains a reserved word or character not escaped properly for the import.  Since you only have 14 columns I would try importing each column individually and see if you get the error on a specific column(s) do it for all of them.  If you get an error importing a specific column focus attention on that column and specific rows.  Break the data into a binary search cutting it in half each time until you find a record that can't import; then find out why. Last, Look for additional records with similar data and correct.

Comment: @xQbert Oh wow thats very helpful. Thanks very much for those suggestions I will try them!